# onPrepareOptionsMenu not being called, MenuItem not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, menuitem

I have three `fragments`: `R.id.splashFragment`, `R.id.selectionFragment`, and `R.id.userSettingsFragment`

And I have a `MenuItem` called `settings`

How I want the app to work:

`splashFragment` is the main screen.

Then when I click on a `Login Button` in the `splashFragment`, the screen shows the `selectionFragment` and `MenuItem`.

Finally, when I click on the `MenuItem`, the screen is redirected to the `userSettingsFragment`.

Problem:

When I click on the `Login Button` the screen successfully shows the `selectionFragment`. However, the `MenuItem` does not show, and therefore I cannot see the `userSettingsFragment` either.

To show the `MenuItem` I override the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method. However, after debugging, I noticed that `onPrepareOptionsMenu` never gets called, and as a result, the `MenuItem` never gets displayed.

Can someone please explain why `onPrepareOptionsMenu` never gets called? Or why `MenuItem` does not show on the screen and possibly offer a solution?

Thanks.

**EDITED CODE** includes more fragment code
**EDITED CODE** now includes all code

code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    private static final int SPLASH = 0;
    private static final int SELECTION = 1;
    private static final int SETTINGS = 2;
    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SETTINGS +1;

    private MenuItem settings;

    private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

    private boolean isResumed = false;

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = 
        new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, 
                SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // only add the menu when the selection fragment is showing
        if (fragments[SELECTION].isVisible()) {
            if (menu.size() == 0) {
                settings = menu.add(R.string.settings);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            menu.clear();
            settings = null;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.equals(settings)) {
            showFragment(SETTINGS, true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragments[SPLASH] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
        fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);
        fragments[SETTINGS] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.userSettingsFragment);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            if (i == fragmentIndex) {
                transaction.show(fragments[i]);

            } else {
                transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
            }
        }
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }   

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
        isResumed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
        isResumed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // Only make changes if the activity is visible
        if (isResumed) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            // Get the number of entries in the back stack
            int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            // Clear the back stack
            for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
                manager.popBackStack();
            }
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                // If the session state is open:
                // Show the authenticated fragment
                //              invalidateOptionsMenu();  ???
                showFragment(SELECTION, false);

            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                // If the session state is closed:
                // Show the login fragment
                showFragment(SPLASH, false);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // if the session is already open,
            // try to show the selection fragment
            //          invalidateOptionsMenu();  ???
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        } else {
            // otherwise present the splash screen
            // and ask the person to login.
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does anybody have any suggestions? Can the issue be with the lifecycle? Do I need to add something in the onCreate?  How do I display the MenuItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When switching to `SelectionFragment` you have to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. This forces the system to refresh the action items and thus recall `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` .

From Fragment code, you have to get you activity first: `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();`

Comment: thanks for the answer. this seems right but i do not know where to put that code... I have edited my post with more Fragment code. Would you be able to tell me where to put the invalidateOptionsMenu()? Also, getActivity() is not recognized in some of the functions. Where should everything go?

Comment: There are a few good points to put it in. Try calling it from the `userSettingsFragment` onCreate. It depends on how you are managing your fragments.

Comment: I tried for an hour but can't figure it out... I posted all my code. Would you be able to help? I do not have an onCreate for userSettingsFragment. Maybe you can figure out where it needs to go...

Comment: I gave a quick look, I think you could call `invalidateOptionsMenu();` right after (or before)                 `transaction.show(fragments[i]);`. Use `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();` for API<11.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new at this. onPrepareOptionsMenu() may be fine -- I haven't looked it up. But, in my FragmentActivity, I'm using onCreateOptionsMenu():

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_page_view, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i tried implementing your method but it did not work. I think there is an issue between my activity and fragments. I need to bind them together correctly.